# Write the git change log in a file

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I want to write the git changelog in a file;
 I used these commands

```
git log --pretty=format:'%h : %s' --graph > /tmp/log.log

git log --pretty=format:'%h was %an, %ar, message: %s' > /tmp/log1.log
```

It stores the entire logs for the repo.

then I used:

```
git log - --since='2 sunday ago' --until='1 sunday ago' --format='%Cgreen%ci%Creset %s%Creset'
```

It stores the logs based on the time period.

In Jenkins used the git changelog plugins, under that chose the create file option, but I m not able to get the logs in a file.

my need is:

I want to store the git change logs in a file and merge it to master branch.

git change logs needed for:

1) current build and last one

2) user defined build numbers

Eg: build 1 and build 11

3) For particular branch in that repo

I'm using Jenkins to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

This should work :

```
git log > someFileName.txt
```

Comment: I hope, this will create the log file with all the logs in that repo. 
But
i need the git change logs needed for:

1)current build and last one

2) user defined build numbers

Eg: build 1 and build 11

3) For particular branch in that repo
I m using Jenkins to implement this;

Answer (score 0):

From version 2.0 of [Git Changelog Plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/git-changelog-plugin), you can get the changelog as a string in a Pipeline. And then just use built in pipeline step to write it to a file.